# Want to receive json response for GET request. Postman gives me the json data. But when I do it programatically it returns empty html

Tags: json, python-2.7

```
import requests
import json

#Infrastructure API URL
    url = "http://10.39.188.69/server-manager/tomcat/bimws/rest/v1/infrastructures/?format=json"
    myResponse = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    print myResponse
    print(myResponse.status_code)
    #print(myResponse.text)
    print(myResponse.json)
```

Output i get:

```
    c:\automation>python rest_API.py
    C:\Python27\lib\site-
    packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:852:
    nsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding 
    certificate verification is strongly advised. See: 
    https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/late/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:852:
nsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certifica
e verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/late
t/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
<Response [200]>
<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing **myResponse.json()**. *myResponse.json* returns an *instancemethod* type while *myResponse.json()* will return the *json data*.

Comment: Response.json() did not help. got Valueerror : No json object could be decoded.

Comment: can you print type of myResponse.  print type(myResponse)

Comment: It returns <Response [200]>
<class 'requests.models.Response'>

Comment: try this : rs = grequests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
resp = grequests.map(rs)
print type(resp[0].json())